# How to disable ListView select visual effect and draw a rectangle around item instead?

Tags: c++, c, listview, winapi

When a ListView item is selected, its color changes to indicate that it is selected. Now what I want to do is to disable this visual effect and implement my own, so for example I want when an item is selected to draw a rectangle around the item.

How can I do that? (Note that I am talking about the Icon view).

Comment: You might want to try setting [`LVS_EX_BORDERSELECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.85).aspx) extended listview style. It seems to me that this is what you want, and this is much easier than custom draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case for [custom draw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761817%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)ing of controls.

It's all about handling the [NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775528%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification and then to draw the control more or less by yourself.

I've never done it by myself changing the appearance seriously but I've change background colors of controls using this mechanism.

There is a lot of information about this on the internet...